# How to send OnActivityResult To a specific page in xamarin forms

Tags: events, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, renderer

I am using a custom button renderer for google sign In in xamarin forms page its working fine I get the signin resultin MainActivity Now i want to send this data from MainActivity and AppDelegate to the Particular page in Xamarin Forms.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 9001)
            {
                Utilities.Configuration.UpdateConfigValue(Utilities.Constants.loggedInflag,string.Empty);
                GoogleSignInResult result = Android.Gms.Auth.Api.Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);

                if (result.IsSuccess)
                {

                    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.SignInAccount;
                    var token = acct.IdToken;
                    //I wan to send the 'accnt' to a Page in xamarin forms

                }
                else
                {
                    //Signin Failure send response to Page in xamarin forms
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: use MessagingCenter

Comment: @YuriS Somewhere i read that using messaging center is Bad, is it okay to use It in this context.

Comment: Different people have different preferences. It is not Bad. The main concern is maintainability.